# Intellisense states a parameter for a strongly typed DataSet query is a Decimal when it should be a String

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, parameters, intellisense, strongly-typed-dataset

We have this query for a strongly typed DataSet which as created in the Visual Studio DataSet Designer:

```
SELECT ID, PaymentAmount, PaymentDate, WhatWasPaymentFor
  FROM Payments
 WHERE ParentID = @ParentID
   AND (@PaymentDate is null OR PaymentDate = @PaymentDate)
   AND (@PaymentAmount is null OR PaymentAmount = @PaymentAmount)
   AND ((@SearchValue is null OR 
       (WhatWasPaymentFor LIKE '%' + @SearchValue  + '%' OR @SearchValue='ALL'))
       )
```

In a VB.Net code-behind file we call the query to fill the DataSet like this:

```
Dim tblObject = theTableAdapter.GetDataByAllInOne(dcmParentsId, Nothing, Nothing, TextBoxSearch.Text)
```

Intellisense shows the 4th parameter as being a Decimal when I thought it would be a String. I found this out when the mouse is over the parameter for @SearchValue.

When this coding is executed, this error is displayed:

```
Conversion from string "Books" to type 'Decimal' is not valid.
```

The only column in this query that is a Decimal is PaymentAmount which happens to be the 3rd parameter not the 4th one.

I'm not sure why intellisense states that the 4th parameter @SearchValue is a Decimal. Can you show me how to change it to a String?

An interest thing that does happen is that the query will work ok if run in the SQL Server Magagement Studio as:

```
DECLARE @SearchValue VARCHAR = 'Books'
DECLARE @ParentID    INT = 3
DECLARE @PaymentDate DATETIME = NULL
DECLARE @PaymentAmount MONEY = NULL

SELECT ID, PaymentAmount, PaymentDate, WhatWasPaymentFor
  FROM Payments
 WHERE ParentID = @ParentID
   AND (@PaymentDate is null OR PaymentDate = @PaymentDate)
   AND (@PaymentAmount is null OR PaymentAmount = @PaymentAmount)
   AND ((@SearchValue is null OR 
    (WhatWasPaymentFor LIKE '%' + @SearchValue  + '%' OR @SearchValue='ALL'))
       )
```

Maybe there is something that needs to be set in the DataSet designer I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the designer, the query will display the parameters it expects in the order it expects them ie you should see something like GetDataByAllInOne(@ParentID,@PaymentDate,@PaymentAmount,@SearchValue).
Can you check this first?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I believe it's in the same order but I will have to confirm that tomorrow since my workplace was closed due to snow today.

Comment: Intellisense shows: GetDataByAllInOne(ParentID As Integer, PaymentDate As Date?, PaymentAmount As String, SearchValue As Decimal?) I'm not sure why intellisense is sticking question marks (?) there as well. At the beginning of the post is how I defined the query in the designer. Thanks.

Comment: The question marks indicate that they are nullable types - you are calling them with nothing as a parameter, so they do need to be nullable types for this. Intellisense is showing the params the query expects. When you say 'how I defined the query in the designer' that's not what I meant. I meant in the bottom half of the tableadapter, in the dataset designer, your queries are listed along with the parameters they expect. As you can see from the intellisense, they are not always the same order as when you typed them in.

Comment: just looked at this again - it appears you have SearchValue and PaymentAmount crossed over somewhere. Try rebuilding the query in the designer.

Comment: Just rebuilt it but it's still looking for a Decimal for the 4th parameter. Maybe this is a Visual Studio bug?

Comment: In the designer, select your query, rt-click, select Properties, in the Properties window open parameters (collection) and in there you can see all the details of the parameters.

Comment: That was it !!! The parameters in the collection were not correct and it let me fix them. You came to the rescue :-)